# Assign the "Asynchronous result" of http call to an object in "For loop"

Tags: angular

I am trying to assign the response to an object in "for loop". Since it is an asynchronous call I am not able to map it properly.

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i]) {
        var obj = {};
        obj['id'] = data[i]['id'];
        obj['firstName'] = data[i]['firstName'];
        obj['lastName'] = data[i]['lastName'];
        if (data[i]['profilePic']) {
          this.getMedia(data[i]['profilePic']['mediaId']).toPromise().then(function (res) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
              obj['src'] = reader.result;
            }, false);

            if (res) {
              reader.readAsDataURL(res);
            }
          });
        }
        if (!this.containsObject(obj, this.slides)) {
          this.slides.push(obj);
        }
      }
    }
```

```
  public getMedia(data: number) {

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrlBackend + '/files/' + data, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.cookie.get('authToken')),
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
  }
```

I expect that "reader.result" should get assigned to the "obj['src']" along with the other objects.

```
 obj['id'] = data[i]['id'];
        obj['firstName'] = data[i]['firstName'];
        obj['lastName'] = data[i]['lastName'];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sounds like you need to use RxJS's map method: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Comment: @jburtondev, Thanks for pointing me to the URL. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implemented this kind of functionality with fork join, i have used this in my project which run pefect. here i am pasting code for your understanding only, please implement like this

```
import { Observable,  } from 'rxjs';  
   fetch(data:Arrau<any>){
    let tempTotalRequest = new Array<any>();    
    data.map((d)=>{ //use map 
            var obj = {};
            obj['id'] = data[i]['id'];
            obj['firstName'] = data[i]['firstName'];
            obj['lastName'] = data[i]['lastName'];
            if (data[i]['profilePic']) {
            tempTotalRequest.push(this.getMedia(data[i]['profilePic']['mediaId']));          
     return Observable.forkJoin(tempTotalRequest).map((element) => {    
          // you can handle response of request   
    let tempData=new Array<any>();  
    element.map((data)=>{     
     let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                      obj['src'] = reader.result;
                    }, false);

                    if (res) {
                      reader.readAsDataURL(res);
                    }
              return  tempData;
            });      
        });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a data structure where on of the key is based on responses of the `getMedia`.

> A simpler way would be to make this code behave synchronous using
>   `async/await`.

1. Tag the method containing this for loop with `async` keyword.
2. Use the `await` keyword to wait for the response.

Example:

```js
async methodName() {
        ... some other code
        .
        .

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i]) {
            var obj = {};
            obj['id'] = data[i]['id'];
            obj['firstName'] = data[i]['firstName'];
            obj['lastName'] = data[i]['lastName'];
            if (data[i]['profilePic']) {
            const res = await this.getMedia(data[i]['profilePic']['mediaId']).toPromise();
            if (res) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                obj['src'] = reader.result;
                }, false);

                if (res) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(res);
                }
            }
            }
            if (!this.containsObject(obj, this.slides)) {
            this.slides.push(obj);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi this approach also work , in this all request will be sent in sequence(sync manner ) for example when one request complete then second request  will be sent. this approach will take more time  as compared to RxJS's fork.join in this all request will be  sent  in  async manner they will join at the end

Comment: Hi, Using async and await keywords I was able to get the calls in sequence,  But under resulted objects the first object was missing the src results and it was mapped to second object, and second src object to third object and so on...

Comment: You will also need to address, the file loading implementation once you get the `res` from the API call. Since the `readAdDataURL` and  `load` operations are also async operations which could be causing the shifting object order.